# How may I use Umlaute programmatically to show up correctly in PyQGIS messagebar?

Tags: pyqgis, gui

So far I couldn't figure out how to write something like u"Einstellungen aus ArcView übernehmen" to show up correctly as the titel of my messagebar. At least I can save my source (although this seems to depend heavily on the editor) by marking it as

## -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*- .

But it doesn't give me the desired result for my messagebar. I also tried .encode('latin1'), which helped for writing the string correctly to a file, but not for displaying it correctly in the messagebar.
Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two steps:
- add a line that indicates [UTF-8 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) to the top of your script
- add the letter *u* (to indicate unicode) **before** the string that contains the umlaut

For example, the following snippet:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from qgis.gui import QgsMessageBar

iface.messageBar().pushMessage('Hallo', u'PyQGIS könnte einfacher sein!', QgsMessageBar.WARNING, 2)
```

Would return this:
[image]

Comment: That indeed solves my question. But now another problem arises, which I had thought to solve by adding the coding: iso-8859-1 statement:

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't used to the functionality of the return key on this site. Actually, it looks like the original problem I tried to solve by adding iso-8859-1 statement doesn't exist with the editor provided by the QGIS Python console (not the one you start by editing a script directly in the toolbox). But nevertheless sooner or earlier one question is left open with your solution: what, if 'PyQGIS könnte einfacher sein!' had been written to a variable? What other form can you use to mark it as a unicode string? (You can't write the u in front of the variable name)?

Comment: The *u* always has to be placed in front of the string that contains an umlaut. As you said, you cannot prepend a variable with the *u*, but you can prepend *the string that goes into* the variable. To take your example and putting it into a variable called *info*: info = u'PyQGIS könnte einfacher sein!'

Comment: Thank you for your answers! As a beginner in PyQGIS programming I appreciate them very much. What I'm still puzzling about - in my case I'm working with DDE-answers by ArcView, which are always strings I only can accept via variable, and more common cases would deal with user input put into a variable via a dialog box. How can I display such strings correctly? Your solution helped me to take over filenames with Umlaut, so I can load those files programmatically, and QGIS displays them correctly in the layer legend, but I wouldn't know how to form a message displaying those names correctly(?).

Comment: So, you are trying to accept user input with umlauts and not have the program crash? What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22773961

Of course, you would not be using *raw_input()* but some method provided by PyQGIS/PyQt. There might be various ways to get user input.

Comment: I've got no idea why, but meanwhile I get correct messages and also log entries into a file no matter if the input is title=u"Einstellungen aus ArcView übernehmen" or srcfile="2013_lrt-kartierung_föa.shp" (transmitted via DDE). I found that after trying the answer of the post linked above, which didn't work. So I am just happy and hope, the behaviour stays like that forever. Interestingly, the only thing that doesn't work is merging both into one string - I can send a mixed message (title, srcfile+" transfered"), but I won't succeed in sending a message (title+srcfile+" transfered").

Comment: But did you use a *u* before *both* of the strings you are merging? If so, it should be no problem.

Comment: No, srcfile had been assigned via DDE, so there is no way to give it a leading u. But that's ok, I think. Later I discovered that there must be three types of strings in my code, being handled differently when I write them into a file. I guess that was initially the reason why I had tried to solve the problem with the changed iso coding. But you convinced me to stay with the utf-8 (which made things better again), and I gave up on trying to understand that issue completely. At least I get DDE-strings the right way and messages / layertreeview entries that look nice, that's most important.